# Finding vectors with highest values in R

Tags: r

I have a series of vectors:

```
aaa<-11
bbb<-23
ccc<-24
ddd<-26
eee<-89
fff<-89
ggg<-100
```

How can I identify all variables that are equal to or exceed the second largest number? In the example above, ideal results would be:

```
  ggg    eee    fff 
  100    89     89
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you had a list of variable names:

```
n <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg")
```

You could get all their values:

```
vals <- unlist(mget(n))
```

You could then find the second largest value:

```
(second.largest <- sort(vals, decreasing=TRUE)[2])
# eee 
#  89
```

and then grab the values that are at least that large:

```
vals[vals >= second.largest]
# eee fff ggg 
#  89  89 100
```

If you instead had the variables stored by name in a list `l`, you could skip defining `n` and just do `vals <- unlist(l)`.

Comment: Yeah, the first point is the most important. The disparate variables should be put in `vals` and never taken back out: `rm(list=n)`

Comment: thank you guys!!  Frank, what do you mean by never taken back out?

Comment: He means that if you're analyzing all these variables together (as your question indicates you are) they should be stored together instead of separately. This allows you to do thing like sorting and subsetting easily, and you can still access the individual values (using, e.g. `vals["aaa"]`).

Answer (score 2):

Or you could also do this

```
a = mget(c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"))
b = do.call(data.frame, a)
out = b[b %in% unique(t(b[order(b, decreasing =T)]))[1:2]]

#> out
#  eee fff ggg
#1  89  89 100
```